# Can't implement search filter to my table data using NSPredicate

Tags: ios, uitableview, search, filter, nspredicate

Now my search work by `sectionsTitle`, if I write "Category1" or "Category2" it find section Category1, or Category2, but I need to search by NAMES in all this sections, from here:

```
NSDictionary *dict = [[tableData objectForKey:[sectionsTitle objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [dict objectForKey:@"Name"]];
```

**What I need to change in my code for search by Names? Now I'm confused with all that NSArray's, NSMutableArray's and NSDictionary :(**

I load my data like this:

```
NSArray *documentPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *path = [[documentPaths lastObject] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"data.plist"];
NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:path];

NSMutableDictionary *resultDic = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
NSMutableArray *resultArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

sectionKeys = [NSMutableArray new];
sectionsTitle = [NSMutableArray new];


        if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"blueKey"])
        {

            ann = [dict objectForKey:@"Category1"];
            [resultArray addObject:@"Category1"];
            [resultDic setValue:ann forKey:@"Category1"];
            [sectionKeys addObject:@"Section 1"];

        }


        if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"yellowKey"])
        {
            ann = [dict objectForKey:@"Category2"];
            [resultArray addObject:@"Category2"];
            [resultDic setValue:ann forKey:@"Category2"];
            [sectionKeys addObject:@"Section 2"];

        }


self.tableData = resultDic;
self.sectionsTitle = resultArray;

[myTable reloadData];
```

This is how I filter data:

```
- (void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString*)searchText scope:(NSString*)scope
{
    NSPredicate *resultPredicate = [NSPredicate
                                    predicateWithFormat:@"SELF contains[cd] %@",
                                    searchText];
    searchResults = [sectionsTitle filteredArrayUsingPredicate:resultPredicate];

}

-(BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller
shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString
{
    [self filterContentForSearchText:searchString
                               scope:[[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar scopeButtonTitles]
                                      objectAtIndex:[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar
                                                     selectedScopeButtonIndex]]];

    return YES;
}
```

This is how my table look like:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {

        if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
            return 1;
        }else{
        return sectionKeys.count;
        }

}


- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {

        if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
            return @"Search";
        }else{
            return [sectionKeys objectAtIndex:section];
        }

}



- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

        if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {

            return [searchResults count];

        } else {
            int num = [[tableData objectForKey:[sectionsTitle objectAtIndex:section]] count];
            return num;
        }

}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        if (cell == nil)
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];


        if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {

             cell.textLabel.text = [searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        } else {
            NSDictionary *dict = [[tableData objectForKey:[sectionsTitle objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];


            cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Avenir" size: 16.0];
            cell.detailTextLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Avenir" size: 12.0];

            cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [dict objectForKey:@"Name"]];
            cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [dict objectForKey:@"Address"]];

        }

        return cell; 
}
```

My data structure:

[image]

Comment: I edited the code and added a data structure image

Comment: Each Category have a lot of Dictionaries Item0, Item1 etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a simplified data set (only the Name entry included in the dictionaries), this should reproduce your setup:

```
NSArray *categories = @[
    @[@{@"Name":@"Joe"}, @{@"Name":@"Jane"}],
    @[@{@"Name":@"Anne"}, @{@"Name":@"Bob"}]
];
```

Then the `ANY` operator of NSPredicate will find the array you are after:

```
NSString *nameToSearch = @"Bob";
NSPredicate *catPred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY Name = %@", nameToSearch];
```

To see how this predicate can filter your category array:

```
NSArray *filteredCats = [categories filteredArrayUsingPredicate:catPred];
```

BTW, you might get less confused if you build some custom objects to hold your data instead of relying only on arrays and dictionaries.

Comment: Sorry, I doesn't know how to implement your answer to my code